# How to safely open ports for Cyber Protection Agent

Tags: 18.04, ufw

I have installed the Backup Agent for Linux Servers **"Cyber Protection Agent"** on vps.

I have followed this link https://www.ionos.com/help/server-cloud-infrastructure/cloud-backup/installing-the-backup-agent/installing-the-backup-agent-for-linux-servers/

It has been installed successfully but I get this message in the end:

> Warning: A firewall has been detected in the system.
> Please configure the firewall to allow connections
> to Cyber Protection Agent.

In the link above , they said :

> you need to unblock ports 443, 8443, 7770 -7800, and 44445 in that firewall.

[image]

How can I enable those ports **safely** ? Is it like this ?

```
sudo ufw allow 443
sudo ufw allow 8443
sudo ufw allow 7770
sudo ufw allow 7800
sudo ufw allow 44445
```

Is there any solution ?

Comment: No idea if it's safe, but these commands don't do what the instructions say. They want the **range** of ports from 7770-7800 inclusive opened, not just the endpoints.

Comment: @OrganicMarble , I'll contact the support so.

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/05/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-begins-31-may-2023/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 18.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com//blog/18-04-end-of-standard-support